# how to get a different behaviour for animation inside ngFor Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript

I am recently working with Angular 6, and now I am dealing with angular animations. I have a simple page, with 3 images, and I want to vote on the images, and want the images to move to the right once they are clicked, which is already happening, BUT, all images are moving at the same time.
I would like to have only the image that got the vote to move, but not sure how to do this "division".

Here is a video of my current app working: 
https://youtu.be/fUpqjh07XcU

my html:

```
    <ul class="heroes list-group">
      <li class ="list-group-item col-md-11" *ngFor="let turtle of turtles"
        [class.selected]="turtle === selectedHero"
        (click)="onSelect(turtle);">
          {{turtle.name}}
        <button  type="button" (click)="changePosition('move');" class="btn btn-secondary"> VOTE! </button>
        <img class="turtleImg" [@photoState]="position" src="{{turtle.image}}"  alt="First slide">
      </li></ul>
<div *ngIf="selectedTurtle">
      <h2> Details</h2>
      <div><span> The turtle {{selectedTurtle.name}} has {{selectedTurtle.votes}} votes  </span></div>
      </div>
    <button  type="button" (click)="reset('moveToZero');" class="btn btn-secondary"> RESET! </button>
```

my typescript

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Turtle } from '../turtle';
import { TURTLES } from '../turtles-list';
import { HostBinding } from '@angular/core';
import {
  trigger,
  state,
  style
} from '@angular/animations';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-turtles',
  templateUrl: './turtles.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./turtles.component.css'],
  animations: [
    // animation triggers go here
    trigger('photoState', [
      state('move', style({ 
        transform: 'translateX(100%)'})),
        state('moveToZero', style({ 
          transform: 'translateX(0%)'}))


    ])]
})



export class TurtlesComponent{

  constructor() { }

  position: string;

  turtles = TURTLES;

  selectedTurtle: Turtle;

  onSelect(turtle: Turtle): void {
    this.selectedTurtle = turtle;
    this.selectedTurtle.votes += 1;

  }

  changePosition(newPosition : string) {

    this.position = newPosition;
  }


  reset(newPosition : string) {
    for(let item of this.turtles){
    item.votes = 0;
    }
    this.position = newPosition;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

How to associate each animation to each item, despite the ngFor loop?

Comment: They are all sharing the same variable `position`. If you give the turtle object each a position property it should work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar problem recently and I am going to share what I did to solve it.
First of all, it's happening because you're sharing the same state for all imgs. To solve this, instead to iterate in a list of images, you should interatte in a list of objects that contains the img path and the state. For example:

```
turtles = [
  {
   "path" : "assets/img/1.png",
    "state" : "state1"
   },
  {
    "path" : "assets/img/2.png",
    "state" : "state2"
   }
]
```

Then, you can iterate on it in your view, for example:

```
<div *ngFor=let turtle of turtles">
    <img class="turtle" [@photoState]="turtle.state" [src]="turtle.path">
</div>
```

Now each image has its own state that you can control in your component.ts.

Comment: Thanks @André Pacheco  I did exactly, this, addeed a state, a new parameter to changePosition and used that property instead as the new position. And also changed the trigger in html. Thank you!